# How can I create an anti forgery state token without using the Google API

Tags: google-oauth

I need to create an anti forgery state token in javascript and I cannot use external jar files or the Google API.  Are there any other examples of how to accomplish this that will work for the OAuth 2.0 OpenConnect protocol.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#createxsrftoken) is the info to create an anti-forgery state token

Answer (score 0):

If I had enough rep to make this a comment I would have...

Couldn't you generate a random/unique number with Javascript, send it along with the Google API request, then validate the number you initially generated with the number which Google returns in the callback? That is my understanding of the anti-forgery token. Or you could use an AJAX GET to generate the token server side and validate it server side. Just some ideas, I've never actually tried these so there might be security implications. Also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) (same-origin policy).

The method that your referenced Google example uses to generate the token is pure PHP - an MD5 hash of a random number. You could probably do this in Javascript. Google states:

> One good choice for a state token is a string of 30 or so characters
>   constructed using a high-quality random-number generator. Another is a
>   hash generated by signing some of your session state variables with a
>   key that is kept secret on your back-end.